# When will `find . -exec COMMAND {} +` execute COMMAND multiple times?

Tags: find

If I do

```
find . -exec echo {} +
```

it prints all paths in one line, i.e. command `echo` is only executed once.

But according to `man find`,

> ```
> -exec command {} +
>     ... the number of invocations of the command will 
> be much  less  than  the  number  of matched files. ...
> ```

It seems that in some circumstances the command will be executed multiple times. Am I right? Please exemplify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

POSIX defined `find` [-exec utility_name [argument ...] {} +](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05) as:

> The end of the primary expression shall be punctuated by a <semicolon>
>   or by a <plus-sign>. Only a <plus-sign> that immediately follows an
>   argument containing only the two characters "{}" shall punctuate the
>   end of the primary expression. Other uses of the <plus-sign> shall not
>   be treated as special. If the primary expression is punctuated by a
>   <semicolon>, the utility *utility_name* shall be invoked once for each
>   pathname and the primary shall evaluate as true if the utility returns
>   a zero value as exit status. A *utility_name* or *argument* containing
>   only the two characters "{}" shall be replaced by the current
>   pathname. If a *utility_name* or *argument* string contains the two
>   characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is
>   implementation-defined whether *find* replaces those two characters or
>   uses the string without change.
>
> If the primary expression is punctuated by a <plus-sign>, the primary
>   shall always evaluate as true, and the pathnames for which the primary
>   is evaluated shall be aggregated into sets. The utility *utility_name*
>   shall be invoked once for each set of aggregated pathnames. Each
>   invocation shall begin after the last pathname in the set is
>   aggregated, and shall be completed before the *find* utility exits and
>   before the first pathname in the next set (if any) is aggregated for
>   this primary, but it is otherwise unspecified whether the invocation
>   occurs before, during, or after the evaluations of other primaries. If
>   any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status, the *find*
>   utility shall return a non-zero exit status. An argument containing
>   only the two characters "{}" shall be replaced by the set of
>   aggregated pathnames, with each pathname passed as a separate argument
>   to the invoked utility in the same order that it was aggregated. **The
>   size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that
>   execution of the utility does not cause the system's {ARG_MAX} limit
>   to be exceeded**. If more than one argument containing the two
>   characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.

When length set of file name you found exceed system `ARG_MAX`, the command is executed.

You can get `ARG_MAX` using [getconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html):

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

On some system, actual value of `ARG_MAX` can be different, you can refer [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) for more details.

Comment: I ran an experiment using `find / -exec echo | wc` and measuring the ratio between character count and line count I found that maximum command line length used by `find` is significantly smaller than theoretical POSIX limit, and a lot closer to the `Size of command buffer we are actually using` line in the output from `xargs --show-limits`. This is true for Linux and it may be true for Mac OS implementation of `find`, although `xargs` won't print the value in Mac OS. Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: `--show-limits` is not specify by POSIX, Mac OS implementation of `xargs` does not support it. `find / -exec echo | wc` won't work. Remember that `ARG_MAX` return bytes. And it's maximum length of the arguments to the `exec(3)` functions.

Comment: I know `--show-limits` is not POSIX, though this is not the maximum argument length used by `find`, which uses a smaller value. I don't understand why you say that `find / -exec echo | wc` won't work: in my opinion it is a good way to have an estimate of the real value (and from what I can see, better than using `getconf ARG_MAX`). Also, my filesystem is mostly if not all ASCII character, so the number of characters is approximately the same as the number of bytes.

Comment: @pqnet: use `find / -exec sh -c 'echo $@ | wc -c' _ {} +` isntead.

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong, I actually used `find / -exec echo {} + | wc -lc`

Comment: Does ARG_MAX count in number of characters or number of arguments(strings)?

Comment: @frozen-flame: It returns number of bytes, you must convert to characters if you want.

Answer (score 7):

There is a maximum length of argument list for a new process in POSIX system. `find` will split the execution if the files paths are longer than this. To see the limit on Linux, use `xargs --show-limits` (don't work in Mac OS, if someone knows a better alternative please comment here)

**edit:** stolen straight from Gnouc's answer, the POSIX way to get the maximum length of argument list is `getconf ARG_MAX`. However, I ran an experiment on my mac os machine, and it looks like `find` uses a little more than half that number. This is coherent with the fact that, on system where it works, `xargs --show-limits` tells us that it won't be using the maximum argument length (in this case too it will use about a half that number), however I couldn't find an explanation for that.

**edit 2:** it seems that the only reliable way to determine how many parameters `find` will stick together for each invocation is to experiment, for example by running

```
find / -exec echo {} + | wc -cl
```

As the output from `find` has a line for each `echo` invocation, it is possible to count them using `wc -l`. The total number of bytes `echo`ed is the output of `wc -c` instead. Dividing one by the other you get the average number of bytes in the parameters for each command invocation (albeit a slightly lower value, because of rounding, roughly half the average lenght of a path in your system)

Comment: `xargs` does not use the full maximum argument length because many programs prepend a few additional arguments and then pass the arguments to other programs. If `xargs` fills the arguments to the absolute maximum, such programs break, because there would be no room for those extra arguments.

Comment: @hvd makes sense. But then, is there a POSIX way to know how much of the buffer is used by `xargs` or `find`?

Comment: You can execute it with a very long list of arguments, determining how many arguments were passed in the first invocation (something like `yes . | xargs | head -n 1 | wc -c`) and comparing that to the output of `getconf ARG_MAX`. But, actually trying it on my system, I get a difference is so large that it seems like there is more to this than I am aware of.

Comment: so it boils down to experimenting... I'll update my answer