# How to chmod the files based on the results from find command

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a situation where I need to find the files having World Write (WW) permission 666 and I need to re mediate such files with 664 .. for this I have used this command

```
find /dir/stuct/path -perm -0002 -type f -print > /tmp/deepu/permissions.txt
```

when I execute the command I get the files which have WW permissions.. Now my requirement is like

```
find /dir/stuct/path -perm -0002 -type f chmod 664
```

Is my syntax correct?

Comment: `find /dir/stuct/path -perm -0002 -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about your requirement for a moment. 
Do you (might you possibly) have any executable files (scripts or binaries)
in your directory tree? 
If so, do you want to remove execute permission (even from yourself),
or do you want to leave execute permission untouched? 
If you want to leave execute permission untouched, you should use `chmod o-w` to remove (subtract) **w**rite permission from the **o**thers field only.

Also, as Anthon points out, the `find` command given in the other answer
executes the `chmod` program once for each world-writable file it finds. 
It is slightly more efficient to say

```
find  top-level_directory  -perm -2  -type f  -exec chmod o-w {} +
```

This executes `chmod` with many files at once, minimizing the number of execs.

P.S. You don’t need the leading zeros on the `2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you also please explain what does + at the end do ?

Comment: I can (and, in fact, I think I did), but please type `man find` first.  If you don't understand what it says, try searching this site (or Super User) for "find exec".  And if you _still_ don't understand, then ask about the part that's got you confused.

Comment: Word of caution: using + instead of \; might lead to error if file count goes into thousands

Comment: @assassinatorr: Do you have a source for that claim?  The [POSIX specification for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05) says — If the `-exec` expression is punctuated by a `+`, … the pathnames … shall be aggregated into sets.  The named utility (program) shall be invoked once for each set of aggregated pathnames.  …  The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  does not cause the system’s {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded.  — If the file count goes into thousands, the command (``chmod`` in this example) will be executed a few times.  The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says, “The command line is built in much the same way that **xargs** builds its command lines.”  See also [When will `find . -exec COMMAND {} +` execute COMMAND multiple times?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152717/23408)

Answer (score 3):

`find /dir/stuct/path -perm -0002 -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`

The "{}" represents the file found by find. The "\;" ends the command that needs to be executed.

Comment: It is faster to use `+` instead of `\;` in this case