# Find the last occurence of a string in a given filetype in all subdirectories

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files, grep, find

I have multiple sub-directories each with different depths. I need to search for the last occurrence of a string in a specific file type (say `*.out`). How can I accomplish this?

I have tried:

```
grep -r 'string' **/*.out | tail -1
```

But that gives me only the last string of the last file.

Comment: What's the different between `the last string of the last file` and `the last occurrence of a string`?

Comment: If I have 100 directories with each possessing a file of type .out, I need the command to print out the last occurence of string in all 100 files. The above command only prints it out for one file (which I think is the last file accessed)

Comment: @cuonglm: The difference is the former omits the relevant occurrences in other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use something like:

```
for i in `find . -name "*.out" -type f`;
do
grep -l 'string' $i
grep 'string' $i|tail -1
done
```

With 1st grep you will have filename and below (second grep) the content.

This works as long as the file names don't contain whitespace or `\[*?`. See [cuonglm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202069) for a robust solution.

Comment: Great this works. Is it possible to get the path for the file as well before the grep

Comment: From what I know about grep I can print content of only filename. To print both I can use second grep. See my addon to the answer

Comment: Thank you. It works in my case. Although I think as discussed in other answer, this command will provide me paths of files that don't contain the string.

Comment: No, the script above will print only files, which contain 'string' string inside

Answer (score 2):

Assume you are in parent directory of sub directories:

```
find . -type f -name '*.out' -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    grep "string" /dev/null "$f" | tail -n 1
  done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: This works. Is it possible to obtain the filepath before the grep step? Also what does sh -c & sh {} + do?

Comment: Unfortunately this will print the name of every file with this extension (independent if contain or not the string)

Comment: @WanderingMind: Add `/dev/null` after `"$f"` to trick `grep` to show you the filename.  `sc -c ...` is needed to make the pipe `grep | tail` work.  `sh {} +` sends the filenames to `sh`.

Comment: @WanderingMind: I invite you to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152723/38906 .

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Fixed it!

Comment: Hi I'm trying to pass a string through arguments. But if I replace "string" with "$query" where query is a variable, this does not work. Can you tell me how to pass a string to this script and make it work.

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu` tools, you could use a single invocation of `gawk`:

```
awk '/pattern/{l=$0} ENDFILE{if (l) {print FILENAME ":" l; l=""}}' **/*.out
```

(if line matches store it into `l`; at the end of each file, if `l` is not empty print file name and `l` then reset `l`)

or `sed`:

```
sed -ns '/pattern/h;${x;//{F;p}}' **/*.out
```

(if line matches, copy to `h`old space; if la`$`t line, e`x`change hold space w. pattern space; if it matches, `p`rint `F`ile name and line)
though the output is different  - file name and corresponding last matching line are on separate lines - but if piped to another `sed` e.g.

```
sed -ns '/pattern/h;${x;//{F;p}}' **/*.out |sed '$!N;s/\n/:/'
```

it will mimic `grep` output<sup>1</sup>.
The above assume *bash* (v. 4 with `shopt -s globstar`) or *zsh*. To include hidden files add `shopt -s dotglob` (*bash*) or `setopt dotglob` (*zsh*).

---

<sup>1: as long none of those file names contains newline characters.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` on a GNU system:

```
for f (**/*.out(.)) tac < $f | grep --label=$f -m1 string
```