# Find last occurence of string in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, grep

I need to search multiple log files (all files generated in last 24 hours, all kept in same directory) to find the last occurrence of a string.
This is the command I wrote:

```
find . -mtime 1 | grep fileprefix | xargs grep 'search string' | tail -1
```

But this returns only last line for one file. Any suggestions on how to tweak this to get all the lines?

Comment: did you try to invert tail and last grep ? find . -mtime 1 | grep fileprefix | xargs tail -1 | grep 'search string'

Comment: See also: [Find the last occurrence of a string in a given file type in all subdirectories](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202065)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming GNU facilities:

```
find . -mtime -1 -exec bash -c \
'for f; do tac "$f" | grep -m1 fileprefix; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate purpose of 'bash -c \' as i am already using bash shell. Also purpose of '_ {} +' at the end.

Comment: @Lokesh, you can get `find` to execute commands on files using `-exec`. With `bash -c`, we're spawning a `bash` shell that loops through the files found by `find` and executes `tac .. | grep -m1 fileprefix` on each

Comment: I was trying to extend the string filtering in for loop by including cut command i.e. for f; do tac "$f" | grep -m1 fileprefix | cut -d' ' -f4,7-8   but moment i put cut command it gives me error unexpected end of file. Can you please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @lokesh, use `-d" "` with cut. Double quotes instead of single

Comment: The `find` command can filter for the file prefix; the `grep` shouldn't be needed for that.  It's also surprising that the search string doesn't figure in this answer.

Comment: @jonathanleffler, the OP needs the file contents examined for the string, not the file names

Answer (score 8):

If everything is in a single directory, you could do:

```
for file in *fileprefix*; do
    grep 'search string' "$file" | tail -1
done
```

If these are large files, it might be worth speeding things up by using `tac` to print the file in reverse order (last line first) and then `grep -m1` to match the first occurrence. That way, you avoid having to read the whole file:

```
for file in *fileprefix*; do
    tac file | grep -m1 'search string'
done
```

Both of those assume there are no directories matching `fileprefix`. If there are, you'll get an error you can just ignore. If that's an issue, check for files only:

```
 for file in *fileprefix*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && tac file | grep -m1 'search string'
 done
```

If you also need the file name printed, add `-H` to each `grep` invocation. Or, if your `grep` doesn't support it, tell it to also search through `/dev/null`. That won't change the output but since `grep` is given multiple files, it will always print the file name for each hit:

```
for file in *fileprefix*; do
    grep 'search string' "$file" /dev/null | tail -1
done
```

Comment: “That way, you avoid having to read the whole file” — uh? No, you avoid reading the whole file in grep but you put the whole file through tac instead. It isn't clear to me that this would be faster, though it would depend on whether the match was near the beginning or the end of the file.

Comment: @Gilles no, you don't put the whole file through `tac` either. It will exit as soon as the first match is found. I just tested with a 832M text file and a pattern found on the last line. `grep -m 1 pattern file` tool ~7 seconds and `tac file | grep -m1  pattern` took `0.009`.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . ! -name . -prune -mtime 1 -name 'fileprefix*' \
     -exec sed -se'/searchstring/h;$!d;x' {} +
```

...will work if you have GNU `sed` that supports the `-s`eparate files option  and a POSIX `find`.

You should probably add the `! -type d` or `-type f` qualifiers, though, because trying to read a directory wont be very useful, and further narrowing the range to regular files could avoid a read hanging on a pipe or serial device file.

The logic is incredibly simple - `sed` overwrites its `h`old space with a copy of any input line which matches `searchstring`, then `d`eletes from output all input lines but the last for each input file. When it gets to the last line, it e`x`changes its hold and pattern spaces, and so if `searchstring` was found at all while it read the file the last such occurrence will be autoprinted to output, else it writes a blank line. *(add `/./!d` to the tail of the `sed` script if that is undesirable)*.

This will do a single `sed` invocation per some 65k input files - or whatever your `ARG_MAX` limit is. This should be a very performant solution, and is quite simply implemented.

If you also want the filenames, given a recent GNU `sed` you can write them out to separate lines with the `F` command, or else you can get them printed by `find` in a separate list per batch by appending the `-print` primary after `+`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
find . -mtime -1 -name "fileprefix*" -exec sh -c \
'echo "$(grep 'search string' $1 | tail -n 1),$1"' _ {} \;
```

The above gives you a nice output with the last occurrence of a search string in each file followed by the respective file name after the comma (modify the ",$1" part under echo to change the formatting or remove it if unnecessary). Sample output that searches for '10' search string in  files with a "file" name prefix is as follows:

```
[dmitry@localhost sourceDir]$ find . -mtime -1 -name "file*" -exec  sh -c 'echo "$(grep '10' $1 | tail -n 1),$1"' _ {} \;
Another data 02 10,./file02.log
Some data 01 10,./file01.log
Yet another data 03 10,./file03.log
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
find . -mtime 1 -name 'fileprefix*' -exec grep -Hn 'search string' {} + |
    sort -t: -k1,2 -n | 
    awk -F: '{key=$1 ; $1="" ; $2="" ; gsub(/^  /,"",$0); a[key]=$0} 
             END {for (key in a) { print key ":" a[key] }}'
```

This uses GNU `grep`'s `-H` and `-n` options to always print both the filename and the linenumber of all matches, then it sorts by the filename and linenumber, and pipes it into awk, which stores the last match for each filename in an array, and eventually prints it.

A fairly brute-force method, but it works.