# Why do I end up with 4 invocations instead of 3 when using this find -execdir {} + (plus)?

Tags: find

I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152717/when-will-find-exec-command-execute-command-multiple-times/152719#152719) that you can count the number of invocations of `command` in `-exec command {} +` by piping `| wc -l` to the end of it.

While I understand that `-execdir` is different, in that, for every matching sub-directory that `find` discovers, it runs an invocation of the `command` from the sub-directory it's contained in, if I have more than one file that matches in a sub-directory, shouldn't I end up with the number of invocations equal to the number of matching sub-directories, and **not** the number of invocations matching the number of matching files in those sub-directories?

I am ending up with the latter when I run the following:

```
$ find . -name "bob*" -execdir echo {} + | wc -l
```

The man page for the `execdir command {} +` states that the former should be the case:

> As with the `-exec` action, the `+` form of the `-execdir` will build
>   a command line to process more than one matched file, but any given
>   invocation of `command` will only list files that exist in the same
>   sub-directory.

---

i.e.

I'm getting:

```
./file1inDir1
./file2inDir1
./file3InDir2
./file4InDir3
```

When I'm expecting this, based on the man page:

```
./file1inDir1 ./file2inDir1
./file3InDir2
./file4InDir3
```

Comment: You can't count command invocations in general that way. If the command is `echo` and the arguments are generated by `{} +` and you don't have newlines in your filenames (most people don't) THEN the number of lines is the number of invocations and it works. If command is say `head -n 999000 /dev/urandom` it goes horribly wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a performance issue of `find`. In `findutils` version 4.3.4, a [workaround](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?18466) had to restrict the number of arguments that `-execdir ... {} +` will use to 1. In version 4.5.9 the limit was removed.

See an example:

```
$ mkdir -p dir{1..3}
$ touch dir{1..3}/file1 dir2/file{1..3}
$ find
.
./dir1
./dir1/file1
./dir2
./dir2/file1
./dir2/file2
./dir2/file3
./dir3
./dir3/file1
```

---

With `-execdir {} +`, the command should be executed 3 times. The second invocation should have 3 arguments.

With `find` 4.4.2:

```
$ find-4.4.2 . -name "file*" -execdir sh -c 'echo "Executing $@ in $(pwd)"' find-sh {} +
Executing ./file1 in /path/to/dir1
Executing ./file1 in /path/to/dir2
Executing ./file2 in /path/to/dir2
Executing ./file3 in /path/to/dir2
Executing ./file1 in /path/to/dir3
```

With `find` 4.6.0:

```
$ find-4.6.0 . -name "file*" -execdir sh -c 'echo "Executing $@ in $(pwd)"' find-sh {} +
Executing ./file1 in /path/to/dir1
Executing ./file1 ./file2 ./file3 in /path/to/dir2
Executing ./file1 in /path/to/dir3
```